# How to capture the next value with respect to the constant value?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var a = "expect ${} to any text ${}"
a = "expect ${} to include text ${}"
a = "expect ${} to deepEqual text ${}"
```

I want to get the value next to `to` in the string. For example, that should give me:

```
any
include
deepEqual
```

how should I do that in javascript?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: `.*?to ([a-zA-Z]*) .*` might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**  `.*(?:\bto\b)\s+(\w+).*`

```
var re = /.*(?:\bto\b)\s+(\w+).*/gm;
var str = 'var a = "expect ${} to any text ${}"\na = "expect ${} to include text ${}"\na = "expect ${} to deepEqual text ${}"';
var subst = '$1';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/mO3dB1/4)**

Comment: I forget if JavaScript supports word boundary (`\b`), but you might want to use that after the `(?:to)` capturing group. Otherwise the `\s*` will allow no spaces and will allow things like "toward" to be captured (with "ward" being inferred as the desired keyword).

Comment: That is my mistake, i want to `\s+`. and i only try for your output . other case is not checked by me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no regex expert, but this works, with the regex being `/ to (\w+)/`:

```
var a = "expect ${} to any text ${}";
console.log(a.match(/ to (\w+)/)[1]); // any

a = "expect ${} to include text ${}";
console.log(a.match(/ to (\w+)/)[1]); // include

a = "expect ${} to deepEqual text ${}";
console.log(a.match(/ to (\w+)/)[1]); //deepEqual
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex. Just split twice

```
var str = "expect ${} to any text ${}";
console.log(str.split("to")[1].split(" ")[1]);
```

We are first splitting on `to` so it will result in

```
["expect ${} ", " any text ${}"]
```

and then we are taking the second element and splitting on `" "` which will result in

```
["", "any", "text", "${}"] // take second element from here
```

If you really want regex, it would be `/to\s*(\S+)/` in which 1st group will contain the text.

Comment: should be `str.split("to")[1].split(" ")[1]` not `0`.